# Idle timer python dbus insue when using crontab or ssh

Tags: python

i have this folowing script:

```
from idle_time import IdleMonitor
idle = None
try:
    monitor = IdleMonitor.get_monitor()
    idle = monitor.get_idle_time()
except:
    idle = None

print(idle)
```

this is returning me a erro when i try to execute trought a ssh or in crontab

```
Could not load <class 'idle_time.GnomeWaylandIdleMonitor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/idle_time/__init__.py", line 31, in get_monitor
    return monitor_class(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/idle_time/__init__.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.connection = connect_and_authenticate(bus="SESSION")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jeepney/integrate/blocking.py", line 113, in connect_and_authenticate
    bus_addr = get_bus(bus)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jeepney/bus.py", line 53, in get_bus
    return find_session_bus()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jeepney/bus.py", line 42, in find_session_bus
    addr = os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'
```

how to fix it? or get idletime from linux with crontab

Comment: idle_time is a WIP project in Pre-Alpha stage, so the stability is unreliable. If you could elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve, you'll get a better solution

Comment: Thank you Udaya. i nee dto get the Idle time fron a os. ( idle time = time that user dont make anithing )

Comment: Ssh connections count to in case of linux.

Comment: I couldn't find reliable python implementations for idle-time. Posting a linux package implementation as the answer @Jasar Orion

Comment: The python-idle tag is for Python's IDLE IDE, not non-action idling ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If finding idle-time is the solution you're looking for, the following package can help:

`sudo apt-get install xprintidle`

after successfully installing, just run `xprintidle` on terminal (`sudo` if required) will return the idle time in ms

---

Since you asked for SSH implementations too, it would work with the same package as follows:

`export DISPLAY=:0 && sudo -u <username> xprintidle`

Reference: [Ubuntu Forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202136/how-can-a-script-detect-a-users-idle-time)